# How to save apache access log files to another server

Tags: linux, apache, debian, logfile, logfiles

I want to save my website's apache access log files to another server. In etc/apache2/sites-available/my_website, there is a customlog configuration line and i can give path to it. But i want to give path to another server. First question, is it possible? Second question, if it is possible how to give server ip and path to customlog?
Thanks!

Comment: Not directly in `CustomLog`,  no. Options include sharing and mounting a remote file system via NFS or other sharing protocols, or using a custom script to send the log somewhere else.

Comment: @jcaron thank you.